# How to highlight specific country on world map image

Tags: c++, qt, geolocation, world-map

I have a real-time flow of IPs' data.
I would like to display geodata, corresponding to received IPs, on world map image using QT & C++.
What would you recommend in that case?

PNG or SVG?
Are there any images out better than Wikipedia's blank maps?
What geodata database would you recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a QWidget which subclasses QGraphicsView, with a QImage of the world in the background, and QPolygons representing overlays (in the shape of each country) on top of the map.

Then call update() every few milliseconds. In your overloaded PaintEvent function, check for new data and highlight a country based on where the IPs are from. Keep that country highlighted for a certain number of milliseconds or seconds, and fade its alpha or something.

As for earth imagery, check with NASA. They can provide you with high, high resolution images of earth in your standard map projection.

Comment: Note that the minimum amount of "few milliseconds" depends on the monitor refresh rate. If the refresh rate is 60 Hz, there is usually no need to call update more often than every 16.67 ms. And if the country is highlighted less than for 16.67 ms, it might never show up as such.

Comment: First of all, thank you, for the answer.

As for country shapes, what borders' database would you recommend? Or is there any map & coordinates for QPoligons set?

Comment: If I recall correctly, wikipedia's svg map might be your best bet:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World6.svg

I don't know how you could get the countries out of it, but I know that their outlines exist as svg layers